# How to remove only comments from this code snippet using vim?

Tags: vim

I want to remove all comments from the following code snippet using vim. Please help me in this.

```
int main()
{
  Computer compute;  
  // To create an 'instance' of the class, simply treat it like you would
  //  a structure.  (An instance is simply when you create an actual object
  //  from the class, as opposed to having the definition of the class)
  compute.setspeed ( 100 ); 
  // To call functions in the class, you put the name of the instance,
  //  a period, and then the function name.
  cout<< compute.readspeed();
  // See above note.
}
```

Comment: search-and-replace, rectangle-mode-delete, macro-recording, placing the cursor on each `/` and hitting `x`, and numerous other ways are at your disposal. What have you tried, what didn't work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:g/<Pattern>/d
```

It will delete all lines which match the `<Pattern>`. e.g.

```
:g/\s*\/\//d
```

will delete all lines which has first two non-whitespace  character as `//`.

Comment: To make the pattern more readable, you can use a different separator than slash (see `:help :g`):  `:g#\s*//#d`

Answer (score 0):

There is several way to do this.

The easiest is probably to **use a plugin** like NERDCommenter http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218

If you don't want to install things, then you can use the **visual mode**:
 - `Ctrl + V` to get into column visual mode
 - Select the `//` 
 - then x

You can also **use a macro** with `qa` then delete the `//` of the first line, close the recording with `q`, and replay the macro with `@a`.

Finally, if you are a **regex** fan, then you can do this : `:g/\s*\/\//d`